# sources that neatness brings brocho/mazal

Tags: sources-mekorot, segulah, cleaning, superstition, masechet-moed-katan

I heard in a daf yomi shiur on the end of Moed Katan (27a ‘Couch of Fortune’) that Jews kept an extra neat bed for brocho/mazal.
One of the reasons that he gave was that in general neatness brings brocho/mazal (malach of brocho/mazal).

Were can I find sources for this?

And it seems that even now Jews have a custom to keep a neat home.

Comment: I think some of these segulas are just common sense cause and effect jazzed up to be more spiritual. Brushing your teeth is a segula for not getting cavities; eating oranges is a segula for not getting scurvy.

Answer (score 3):

It says in [Pesachim 111b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=111b&format=text) " איסרא דעניותא נבל שמיה" "The angel over poverty is called dirt"

Rashi, however interprets it as being unclean regarding bread

Comment: 1) A better translation of נבל is probably "filthiness." 2) To clarify: Rashi seems to be discussing a mess of bread crumbs strewn about (on the floor, I assume).

Answer (score 1):

Going out on a limb here. The sister sugya to yours is in Sanhedrin 20a. There the Yad Ramah says that 'this practice is similar to the people who set up a table for Gad (which is assur) except that there, they have intention of worship while here it is only for a good siman'.  What i want add is an explanation of 'siman' based on the gemara in Horios 12a concerning simana milsa and the simanim on the night of Rosh Hashana where a given idea is started and this is a siman, a cause, to be continued. If the bracha/mazal which you are looking for is the blessing of neatness, then this is an option for a source. But it seems this pshat is not working with the Gad mazal of good fortune. For more pshatim see Margolios HaYam there, but nobody he brings says quite like what your magid shiur said.