# What is a Mazal Tov? (A question on Rashi)

Tags: talmud-gemara, rashi, masechet-moed-katan

In Moed Qatan 27a, the gemara refers to a certain type of couch or stool as an ערסא דגדא: a couch of fortune. Rashi explains it as a couch that is only used for showcasing mazal tovs:

מטה שמייחדים אותה למזל טוב ואין משתמשין בה כלום אלא מייחדין אותה לשרות מזל טוב עליה

"A couch that is designated for a *mazal tov*. It is not used at all, save that it is designated for the placement of a *mazal tov* upon it."

What is this mazal tov to which Rashi is referring? A good luck charm?

Comment: http://leemichaelwithers.tripod.com/sfh4_22_97.htm

Comment: IIRC, this concept shows up in several places. From the shiurim I've heard address it, it's not about "showcasing," but that having an unused seat somehow brings mazal (ayin tov?)... If I find a shiur that discusses it more, I'll try to remember to link it.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47652/5120

Answer (score 4):

Rav Yosef Viener explains the mazal Tov of such a couch is that when you have a feeling of having everything you need and then a little extra chesed too (like a couch which you dont use or the "extra" birth of Gad--see rashi on the pasuk) living without showing you need to squeeze every penny, that itself is a good mazal and will activate more good mazal of bracha. The opposite is true also, where feeling down and pressed can bring a mazal Ra r"l and the negative side effects with it.